# How to link the items.py and my spider file?

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and trying to scrape a page which has several links. Which I want to follow and scrape the content from that page as well, and from that page there is another link that I want to scrape.

I tried this path on shell and it worked but, I don't know what I am missing here. I want to be able to crawl through two pages by following the links.
I tried reading through tutorials but I don't really understand what I am missing here.

This is my items.py file.

```py
import scrapy

# item class included here 
class ScriptsItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
```

And here is my scripts.py file.

```py
import scrapy
import ScriptsItem


class ScriptsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scripts'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.imsdb.com/TV/Futurama.html']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.imsdb.com/TV/Futurama.html/']
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.imsdb.com/TV/Futurama.html'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//table//td//p//a//@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        item = ScriptsItem()
        item["link"] = response.url
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//table[@class = 'script-details']//tr[2]//td[2]//a//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
import ScriptsItem
```

to

```
from your_project_name.items import ScriptsItem
```

your_project_name - Name of your project